# После выбора кейса выполнить действие и выбрать другой кейс, а потом выйти

Tags: java, switch

```
package labWork6;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product a = new Product(1, 5, 10);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b, c, d, e;
        menu();
        int choice = in.nextInt();
        while (true) {
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("11");
                    e = in.nextInt();
                    a.setCode(e);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b = in.nextInt();
                    a.setPriceForKG(b);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    c = in.nextInt();
                    a.setWeight(c);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println(
                            "Код продукта: " + a.getCode() +
                                    "Цена за кг: " + a.getPriceForKG() +
                                    "Вес продукта: " + a.getWeight());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(a.getResult());
                    break;
                case 6:
                    int i = 0;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println(" Меню ");
        System.out.println("1.Установить значение кода");
        System.out.println("2.Установить значение цены за 1 кг");
        System.out.println("3.Установить значение веса");
        System.out.println("4.Вывод данных на экран");
        System.out.println("5.Вывод Результата(Цена)");
        System.out.println("6.Выход из программы");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы нам предлагаете самим угадать что не так?

Comment: "оптом вышел" - оптом, конечно, дешевле

Answer (score -1, accepted):

choise добавьте в цикл. он у вас только один раз считывается

Comment: о чем речь??????

Comment: добавить ваш int choice = in.nextInt(); в блок while цикла

Comment: всё, понял, спасибо